# how to time format datetime.now.addhours() in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

Im using this syntax:

```
DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
```

How will I generate a time only format on this syntax?

```
DateTime.Now.AddHours(1).ToString("hh:mm:ss");
```

well ofcourse this is wrong cos of type mismatch.

Comment: Which type are you expecting? You code looks fine to me https://dotnetfiddle.net/b1sdBy

Comment: I think the issue is with the assignment, since you have added `.ToString()` the result will be a string and you have to assign them to a string variable, not to a DateTime variable

Comment: it is not actually wrong. it outputs a string. except if the left side variable is a datetime. DateTime = string output is really wrong

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for an object (not string) that would contain only the time part of a `DateTime` object. In that case use `TimeSpan`.

```
var timeSpan = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1).TimeOfDay;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write the DateTime to a variable

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
```

and format it with one of this then.

```
dt.ToString("HH:mm"); // 07:00 // 24 hour clock // hour is always 2 digits
dt.ToString("hh:mm tt"); // 07:00 AM // 12 hour clock // hour is always 2 digits
dt.ToString("H:mm"); // 7:00 // 24 hour clock
dt.ToString("h:mm tt"); // 7:00 AM // 12 hour clock
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it with variable instead of doing in one line with chaining ToString to AddHours???

Comment: since this example isn't that difficult i thought separating it into two parts would probably make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
string shortTimeFormat = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1).ToShortTimeString();
string otherAlt = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

The return is `string` type;

If you want `DateTime` format:

```
DateTime changedTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pre Estong you can use ToShortTimeString method or ToLongTimeString method.

```
         var changedTime = date.AddHours(1).ToShortTimeString(); // OUTPUT 1:40 PM
         changedTime = date.AddHours(1).ToLongTimeString(); // OUTPUT 01:40:55 PM
```

Hope this helps.